# getting Element's global/document coordinates in Dart (aka $('some').offset())

Tags: dom, dart

Im trying to get the document(global) coordinates of an Element (DOM Element) in Dart, which in pure JavaScript I was able to get via jQuery with $('some_selector').offset().

Ive been looking through the Dart dart:html API's, but no luck so far.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 6):

There's no native function on [Element](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Element.html) to get that coordinates.

Here's a Dart's version of [jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) :

```dart
class Position {
  num left, top;
  Position(this.left, this.top);
}

Position offset(Element elem) {
  final docElem = document.documentElement;
  final box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return new Position(box.left + window.pageXOffset - docElem.clientLeft,
                      box.top  + window.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop);
}
```

An other solution is to use [jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) via [js-interop](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) :

```dart
Position jQueryOffset(Element elem) {
  return js.scoped((){
    final offset = js.context.jQuery(elem).offset();
    return new Position(offset.left, offset.top);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexandre, this would make an excellent feature request at dartbug.com/new :)

Answer (score -2):

You should consider using this Dart Element method : https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Element#id_documentOffset

Comment: It would be a better answer if you would copy the most relevant parts into the answer instead of the the link-only answer.